# Laravel routing to specific folder

Tags: php, laravel

Let me explain.
I know that routing with Laravel is pretty simple, I do things like this :

```
Route::get('{n}','TestController@index');
```

Then, in `TestController`, I can use `$n` as an arguement.
But now I do something a bit different, my controllers are stored in directories within `app/Http/Controllers`, for instance, I can have controllers like this :
`app/Http/Controllers/directory1/TestController`
`app/Http/Controllers/directory2/TestController`
The controller I want to call are named the same, but that's not a big deal, as they are not in the same directories.
Now, since the're not in `app/Http/Controllers` anymore, but in one more folder deep, I need to do something like this :

```
Route::get('{n}','{n}\TestController@index')
```

I need to use `{n}` inside the route in order to build the URL right away, like this, and since $n is not defined at this moment, I don't know how I can do it.
Any tips, or a better wa to do this ? I don't think this method is really good by the way ^^

Comment: If you don't think this is a good idea, then why are you doing this?

Comment: I need to do this, either this way, or a better one, if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the variable value from the url segment

```
$n = ucfirst(Request::segment(1));
Route::get('{n}',$n.'\TestController@index');
```

Comment: It actually worked like i wanted. By the way, is `segment(1)` arbitrary or it is how `Request` works  ? Anyway, this solution does the job :D